# Google Calendar Event with API don't send the Notification mail (.ics)

Tags: calendar

I have a problem with my Web Service.

I created a Web Service with the Google API that create an Event on my Google Calendar and send the e-mail notification to my account.

It works until the last 2 days. From Yesterday it create the event on my Calendar but it don't send the e-mail.

I don't modify the code and it's so strange.

I need to send again the mail because the employees that receive the event need the mail too.

I don't think is a problem of code because the Web Service work from months.

Someone can help me?

Thanks so much

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same problem, as of 2 days ago.

Comment: Have you find some solution? I'm searching from that day but I don't find anything.

Comment: I found a work around, notifications stopped working when the event was created and owned by the service account. I ended up sending invites from a user account instead of the service account. The event is still owned by the service account, the invites come from a user.